# Simple Date Format DateTime gives different result in different android devices

Tags: android, kotlin, simpledateformat

```
fun getDateTimeWithUTC(): String {
val df =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")

return df.format(Date())
```

}

this code gives different results from different devices.. :

wrong format :  31-03-2022-20:08:02

expect :  2022-03-31T18:07:23.6070000Z

Why ?

Comment: If you want consistent results, you definitely need to supply a Locale. But I don't know if that's enough to guarantee it across Android versions.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. I also expect more consistent results from it.

Comment: Are you saying that even though you put the literal `Z` in single quotes in your format pattern string, that `Z` does not come out in the formatted result on all Android devices? `SimpleDateFormat` is even more confusing than I thought, and I already found it extremely confusing.